# File Gets Null While Calling API Through Angular JS. But gets uploaded through postman

Tags: angular, spring, postman

I am calling the upload API of spring boot from angularJS. The file gets null on the Spring controller. Attaching the code and screenshots below for reference.

**upload.js**

```
     this.uploadTenantFile =  function(tenantId, file, callback){
                    console.log("this is file");
                    var url = __env.apiUrl + 'api/tenants/' +tenantId + '/uploadconfig';
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("file", file);
                    console.log(file.name);
                    var collection = {
                                         method: 'POST',
                                         url: url,
                                         data : formData,
                                         transformRequest: angular.identity,
                                         headers:{
                                            'Content-Type': undefined
                                         }

                                     }
                                     $http(collection)
                                     .then(function(response) {
                                         callback(response.data);
                                     })
                          }
```

controller.java

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/uploadconfig")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> upload(@PathVariable("tenantId") Long tenantId,
                                         @FormParam("file")  MultipartFile file)
    {
        String message = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
        log.info(file.getSize());
    }
```

[image: when calling through Angular code]
**when calling through Angular code**

**WHile calling though POSTMAN**
[![When calling though Postman][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hutdL.png